# Multiple compile modes in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I want to use a single make file to generate a project in multiple modes, and then each mode in a "normal" and "debug" mode, ie:

I have the following files (ofc more in reality, but this will serve to show my point):

- kernel/core/main.cpp
- kernel/processor/Processor.cpp
- kernel/processor/x86/Processor.cpp
- kernel/processor/x86_common/Processor.cpp
- kernel/processor/x64/Processor.cpp

And i want to be able to use my makefile in the following ways:

```
make x86
  (compiles all files except "kernel/processor/x64/Processor.cpp")
  (enables the pre-processor directives X86 & X86_COMMON)
```

And,

```
make x86debug
  (compiles all files except "kernel/processor/x64/Processor.cpp")
  (enables the pre-processor directives X86 & X86_COMMON & DEBUG)
  (puts "-g -ggdb" infront of all gcc/g++/as arguments)
```

And so on.

Currently i have the following makefile, which while it works, only lets me compile in x86-debug mode and now that i am porting my software to other platforms I wish to be able to specify what mode to build in.

```
CC = i586-elf-g++
CFLAGS = -g -ggdb -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -std=gnu++11 -Isrc/system/include -DX86 -DX86_COMMON
LD = i586-elf-gcc
LDFLAGS = -g -ggdb -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -lgcc
AS = i586-elf-as
ASFLAGS = -g -ggdb 

OBJECTS = src/system/kernel/core/main.o
ALL_OBJECTS = $(OBJECTS) $(X86_OBJECTS)

X86COMMON_OBJECTS   = src/system/kernel/core/processor/x86_common/Processor.o

X86_OBJECTS = $(X86COMMON_OBJECTS) src/system/kernel/core/processor/x86/boot.o
X86_LINKER  = src/system/kernel/core/processor/x86/link.ld
X86_OUTPUT  = bin/kernel_x86.bin

.PHONY: clean
clean: $(ALL_OBJECTS)
    rm $(ALL_OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all
all: $(X86_OUTPUT)

$(X86_OUTPUT): $(X86_LINKER) $(OBJECTS) $(X86_OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -T $(X86_LINKER) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

As you can probably tell, im not an expert with make so any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to store the mode-specific object files for later use? Do you want to segregate them by filename (`Processor_x86_debug.o`) or in directories (`bin/x86/debug/Processor.o`) or in some combination (`bin/x86/Processor_debug.o`)? And what about the different executables?

Comment: They are separated by directory, and i need to keep the .o files as they are ran through a custom tool to generate extra information and reflection data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `-g` from `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`, and add the following `PHONY`:

```
.PHONY: x86_debug
x86_debug: CFLAGS += -g
x86_debug: LDFLAGS += -g
x86_debug: $(X86_OUTPUT)
```

To compile in normal mode: `make`.
To compile in debug mode: `make x86_debug`

It may not do exactly what you're expecting, but it's easy to modify

Comment: @Mattiemus You are welcome. I struggled with Makefile too :) When your  Makefile gets really complicated, you may want to check out tools such as `cmake`